# Schedule everyday python function and write ouput in excel at eachtime

Tags: python

i'm new using Python 3.6 and I have a main function that I want python to run everyday while writing down the given output in a different file each time.
In this moment my code is:

```
 #This is the child function I created
from ObtainsDistancesfromGoogleforRange import obtaindistance

def main():

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

passwords=['a', 'b']
ranges=[(1,2),(2,3)]


# Creates separate text files by passing the range for each file to the function obtaindistance, and then executing all instances of the function in parallel
proc=[]
for rangeind in range(0,len(passwords)):    
    password=passwords[rangeind]
    rangestart=ranges[rangeind][0]
    rangeend=ranges[rangeind][1]
    p = Process(target=obtaindistance,args=(password,rangestart,rangeend))          
    proc.append(p)

print(proc)

# Runs all processes in parallel
for p in proc:
    p.start()
for p in proc:
    p.join()    

# Appends the text files
output_f=open(os.path.join(dir,'Distances.csv'),'w',newline='')
output_writer=csv.writer(output_f)
output_header=['Destination','Origin','Date-time of query','Distance (meters)','Duration (seconds)','Duration in Traffic (seconds)', 'Query status']
output_writer.writerow(output_header)
for rangeind in range(0,len(passwords)):
    rangestart=ranges[rangeind][0]
    rangeend=ranges[rangeind][1]
    dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    input_f=open(os.path.join(dir,'DistancestoMarkets_'+str(rangestart)+'_'+str(rangeend)+'.csv'))
    output_f.write(input_f.read())

#Close files
output_f.close()
input_f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to make my script run everyday at a different hour. I´ve tried out APScheduler but I haven´t been able to make it work. Any ideas?
Also I think there may be a problem because I´m telling the script to create a new csv file each time it runs with the same name, so I think I have to modify it so that at each run it saves the information it downloads in a different document.
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an operating system thing. A python script can't run itself. Perhaps look into e.g. batch scripts if you're on Windows.

Comment: Or cron on Linux.

Comment: Re-reading, the issue is that you're overwriting data each day because you save to a file with the same name?

Comment: I´m on Windows. Could you explain that a little bit more? @Denziloe
I can make it run at a certain time using this code:
    x=datetime.datetime.today()
    y=x.replace(day=x.day+0, hour=16, minute=20, second=0, microsecond=0)
    delta_t=y-x
    secs=delta_t.seconds+1
    def main():
...
    t = Timer(secs, main)
    t.start()
.
But I want it to run everyday

Comment: They're trying to say that unless you leave your program running infinitely, you won't be able to start up your program at a certain time unless you use cron (linux) or at (windows)

Comment: I'm reading between the lines here massively. So you call a script at regular intervals and each script terminates. You've hard-coded a file name and it overwrites the data each time the script runs. You need an external counter stored somewhere so that the script reads it each time it's run and gets a unique file name, then increments that counter in that file.

Answer (score 1):

To run a program every day, the easiest way is to use the scheduler of Windows (the Task scheduler) so it will be the operating system that will run your script.

To avoid the overwriting of the output file every day, you have two ways:

1. open the file in append mode with `output_f=open(os.path.join(dir,'Distances.csv'),'a',newline='')`
2. append a timestamp to the file name, so every day you will create a file with a different name (and you will be able to easily retrive a file from a certain day if you need it).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use something derived from the system time to augment your file name.  For instance:

```
import time
file_name = "Distances" + str(int(time.time()) + ".csv"
```

If you want the file name to be more human-friendly, use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) package instead.

For your initial problem, I concur with the others: use your operating system's scheduling to make this run every day at a desired time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I used task scheduler with the recomendations for running python scripts from this blog: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/

And I had a new directoy created for each time I ran the script.

```
    datetimeid= datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(),'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') #Define the datetime as a string in the format YearMonthDay - HourMinuteSecond
output_dir = os.path.join(dir,datetimeid) #Create a new folder with the date-time of execution
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
```